# Does this indicate there is a GPU installed on the machine?

Tags: gpu

```
[martin@A08-R32-I196-2-FZ1RLP2 ~]$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:3a00-39ff iomemory:3a80-3a7f memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:3a000000000-3a7ffffffff memory:3a800000000-3a801ffffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:3b00-3aff iomemory:3b80-3b7f memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:3b000000000-3b7ffffffff memory:3b800000000-3b801ffffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G200eR2
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=0 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:17 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:93800000-93803fff memory:93000000-937fffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:83:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:3e00-3dff iomemory:3e80-3e7f memory:cd000000-cdffffff memory:3e000000000-3e7ffffffff memory:3e800000000-3e801ffffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:84:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:3f00-3eff iomemory:3f80-3f7f
```

If yes, what's the model?

EDIT per suggestion:

```
[martin@A08-R32-I196-2-FZ1RLP2 anaconda3]$ lspci -vvv | head
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DMI2 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
        Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be hit or miss with `lshw` whether you get meaningful product/vendor details. In your cases you're getting a mixed bag of results. The NVidia hardware is too generic, the Matrox seem pretty dead on as to what hardware version it is:

```
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation

   product: G200eR2
   vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
```

I've had better luck with just using `lspci` for this instead:

```
$ lspci -vvv | head
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 128
        Region 0: Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 2: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
                        ExtTag- RBE+
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee0800c  Data: 4142
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] #1b
        Capabilities: [200 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
                ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
                ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
        Capabilities: [300 v1] #13
        Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
        Kernel modules: i915_bpo

The key thing to do with `lspci`
```

AS you can see the above has much more detail about the video card.

Comment: please see my addition. It doesn't look like a GPU installed. right?

Comment: @user697911 - was there no output regarding the video card when doing `lspci -vvv`? If that's truly all the output you received, there's no GPU listed.

Comment: Yes. That's all I received.

Comment: @user697911 - yeah so no GPU details.

Comment: But these are our new machines and they are supposed to be GPU servers. Any other command to check?

Comment: All the methods that I've historically used are shown here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to BIOS Settings to ensure that Dedicated GPU is enabled.
If Dedicated GPU is disabled by mistake in BIOS. Commond `lspci` won't show GPU details.

Once sure that dedicated GPU is enabled do step as suggested by slm